# Conditions for the restriction $H^i(G,A)\to H^i(H,A)$ being surjective

Tags: group-cohomology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I was wondering what the condition is for the restriction map (in group cohomology)  $H^i(G,A)\to H^i(H,A)$ to be surjective.

I am a little confused about when maps between cohomology groups are considered to be $G$-, $H$- or $G/H$-module homomorphisms. In particular, in the exact sequence of low degrees

$0\to H^1(G/H,A^H)\to H^1(G,A)\to H^1(H,A)^{G/H}\to H^2(G/H,A^H)\to H^2(G,A)$

are the maps all meant to be $G$-module homomorphisms?

EDIT: Does someone have an example when $\mathrm{res}$ is not surjective?

Comment: The cohomology groups are not $G$-modules.

Comment: At the very least $H^1(H,A)$ should be a $G/H$-module.

Comment: @Angelo, if $A$ is a $G$-module, and if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the conjugation action of $G$ on $H$ together with the given action of $G$ on $A$ induces an action of $G$ on the cohomology group $H^i(H,A)$. It turns out that this action factors through the quotient group $G/H$. You also obtain an action of $G$ on $H^i(G,A)$, though this action turns out to be trivial. Similarly, $G/H$ (hence also $G$) acts trivially on $H^i(G/H,A^H)$.

Comment: @s.barmeier, along the lines of my previous comment, the maps are all $G$-module homomorphisms, though all of the spaces in the exact sequence are trivial $G$-modules, so this isn't saying very much.

Comment: How about on the cochain level, before taking quotients by the groups of coboundaries. Are these maps $G\times\dotsb\times G\to A$ subject to any module structure conditions?

Comment: To Christopher: ok, I should have said that those cohomology groups are not $G$-modules in a non-trivial way. This reminds me of a talk I gave when I was young, with a great mathematician in the audience. I said something like "homology of singular spaces does not have a natural ring structure"; this really upset him, and objected very loudly "sure it does: you could define all products to be 0".

Comment: Another exact sequence that you could consider is $... \to H^i(G,A) \to H^i(G,\operatorname{Ind}_H^G A) \to H^i(G,(\operatorname{Ind}_H^G A)/A) \to ...$.  (Note that $H^i(G,\operatorname{Ind}_H^G A)=H^i(H,A)$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You asked for examples when $\text{res}^G_H\colon H^i(G;A)\to H^i(H;A)$ is not surjective. Here are some examples for $i=1$.

- Let $G=\text{SL}_2\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $H^1(G;\mathbb{Z})=0$ but $H^1(H;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ so $\text{res}$ is not surjective.
- Let $G=D_\infty=\text{Isom}(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\ltimes\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\text{Isom}^+(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$. Now $[G:H]=2<\infty$ but still $H^1(G;\mathbb{Z})=0$ and $H^1(H;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ so $\text{res}$ is not surjective.
- Let $G$ be the rank 2 free group $G=F_2=\langle a,b\rangle$, and let $H$ be any subgroup of index $n-1$. Then $H$ is a free group of rank $n$ so $H^1(H;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^n$. But $H^1(G;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^2$ so $\text{res}$ is not surjective for $n>2$.
- For a finite example, let $G$ be the group of upper-triangular matrices in $\text{SL}_3\mathbb{F}_p$, and let $H$ be its center: $H=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\ast\\\\0&1&0\\\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Then the map from $H^1(G;\mathbb{F}_p)=\mathbb{F}_p^2$ to $H^1(H;\mathbb{F}_p)=\mathbb{F}_p$ is the zero map (this is a good exercise), so $\text{res}$ is not surjective. (For a related topological example, let $T^1\Sigma_g$ be the unit tangent bundle of an orientable surface of genus $g>1$, let $G=\pi_1(T^1\Sigma_g)$, and let $H\approx \mathbb{Z}$ be its center.)
- More generally, let $G$ be any group and let $H$ be its commutator subgroup $[G,G]$. As long as your coefficients are untwisted (trivial as a $G$-module), the map $H^1(G;A)\to H^1([G,G];A)$ is always the zero map. Thus if $G$ is any group for which $H^1(G;A)\neq 0$ and $H^1([G,G];A)\neq 0$, $\text{res}$ is not surjective. Examples of such $G$ include free groups, surface groups, non-abelian nilpotent groups (either with $A=\mathbb{Z}$ or $A=\mathbb{F}_p$), etc.

You can also get examples for $i=0$ when $A$ is a nontrivial $G$-module, since $H^0(G;A)$ is the $G$-invariant elements of $A$, while $H^0(H;A)$ is the $H$-invariant elements of $A$. Thus  whenever $A$ contains an $H$-invariant element not fixed by $G$, the restriction $\text{res}$ will not be surjective. For example, for $[G:H]<\infty$ you could take $A=\mathbb{Q}[G/H]$.

Comment: Thanks, these examples are really helpful. Although $C^1(G,A)\to C^1(H,A)$ is always surjective the induced $\mathrm{res}$ is not... (I think that is where I got confused before.)

Now, looking at your 4th example, $\mathrm{res}\colon H^1(G,A)\to H^1(H,A)^{G/H}$ is not even surjective in this case. I tried your exercise in the next comment.

Comment: For $[x]\in H^1(H,A)$ define a normalized 1-cochain in $C^1(G,A)$ by $y(\sigma)=y(g)+gx(h)$, where $\sigma=gh$ and $g$ is a coset rep.

Using that $H$ is central, the cocycle condition on $C^1(G,A)$ gives $\partial^1 y+g_1g_2(g_2^{-1}x(h_1)-x(h_1h_2)+x(h_2))=0$. I interpret this to mean that $\mathrm{res}[y]=[x]$ as long as $G$ acts trivially on $A$. But it does, whence my conclusion seems to be that $\mathrm{res}$ is surjective. Except that it isn't.

Comment: I must admit that I didn't follow your argument, but the approach I would take is to show that $H^1(G;\mathbb{F}_p)\approx \text{Hom}(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ for any group $G$ (step 1). Since here $H$ lies in the commutator subgroup of $G$ (step 2), any homomorphisms $G\to \mathbb{F}_p$ restricts trivially to $H$. Thus the restriction map $\text{Hom}(G,\mathbb{F}_p)\to \text{Hom}(H,\mathbb{F}_p)$ is the zero map (step 3). For step 1 you can quote the universal coefficient thm, but I recommend proving it directly with cochains. (This argument only needs $H\subset [G,G]$, but here in fact $H=[G,G]$.)

Answer (score 3):

The following is a small collection of examples.  I am not sure why you are interested in the restriction map being surjective, but I know a big use of restriction maps deals with their kernel, and in fact the intersection of its kernels to all subgroups (called *Essential Cohomology*).

But first, for example by Frobenius reciprocity, the corestriction map $\text{cor}^G_H$ is a homomorphism of $\widehat{H}^\ast(G,A)$-modules. This is better than having the trivial actions of the groups themselves on their cohomology.
Also, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $A$ is a $G$-module, then the conjugation action of $G$ on $(H,A)$ induces an action of $G/H$ on $H^\ast(H,A)$. But yes, $G$ acts trivially on $H^*(G,A)$.  I refer you to Ken Brown's *Cohomology of Groups* for more information.

1) By Mislin's theorem, the restriction map from $G$ to $H$ (a subgroup) on mod-p cohomology is an isomorphism if and only if $H$ controls p-fusion in $G$.
2) A rather trivial example: The inclusion $G\hookrightarrow G\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ induces a surjective restriction map (mod-p coefficients) by functoriality.
3) You can also go the other route and write down all the vanishing and nilpotence results on $H^\ast(H,A)$; there is a ton.

[[Edit]]:  Now the response to the restriction map not being surjective is much heavier, but you can easily just look some of this stuff up in Ken Brown's textbook, so I don't think it should be asked on this forum.

1) If $G$ is finite and $H$ is an abelian sylow-p subgroup, and $A$ is a trivial $G$-module, then the image of the restriction map is $H^\ast(H,A)^{N_G(H)}$.
2) If $|G:H|<\infty$ and $A$ is a field of characteristic $p$ relatively prime to $|G:H|$, then the restriction map is injective, because $\text{cor}\circ\text{res}(z)=|G:H|z$.
3) If $|G:H|<\infty$ and is invertible in $A$ (a $G$-module), then the restriction map sends $H^\ast(G,A)$ isomorphically onto $H^\ast(H,A)^G$.
4) Let $G$ be a $2$-group.  It turns out that $\text{Ker}(\text{res}^G_H)$ is the principal ideal $(x)$, where $|G:H|=2$ and $x\in H^1(G,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a homomorphism $x:G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $\text{Ker}x=H$.  Since the maximal subgroups of a $p$-group are the subgroups of index $p$, we see that every nontrivial element $x$ corresponds to some maximal subgroup $M\subset G$ (which has index $2$) with $\text{Ker}x=M$.

Note, for injective restriction maps, couple it to Mislin's theorem to see when it is not surjective.
You can also take a look at this short paper I wrote of explicit calculations of restriction maps and their kernels: http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4836.

** In fact, given a collection $\mathcal{H}$ of subgroups of $G$, the ring $H^\ast(G,A)$ is said to be *detected* by $\mathcal{H}$ if all the restriction maps associated to $\mathcal{H}$ are injective.  As an example, $H^\ast(G)$ is detected on the set of Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Well, I'm interested in the surjectivity of the restriction, because I am interested in the kernel of the transgression $H^1(H,A)^{G/H}\to H^2(G/H,A^H)$ and the exact sequence in low degrees tells me $\mathrm{im} \mathrm{res}=\ker \mathrm{tg}$. But in all the examples I can think of the restriction map is always surjective (unless there was some $G$-module structure I overlooked, which doesn't seem to be the case). ... which just seems too strange to be true. Hence, I wondered under what precise conditions the restriction is surjective.

Comment: What are your examples?