# When is the restriction map in cohomology an isomorphism?

Tags: group-cohomology

When is the restriction map in cohomology an isomorphism? Let $G$ be a group, $H$ one of its normal subgroups and $M$ a $G$-module. If $H^1(G,M)\simeq H^1(H,M)^{G/H}$, can we conclude that $H=G$?

Comment: I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95036/conditions-for-the-restriction-hig-a-to-hih-a-being-surjective

Comment: see the above link; there is an exact sequence which tells you that in general, there is a map from $H^1(G,M)$ into $H^1(H,M)^{G/H}$ with kernel $H^1(G/H,M^H)$.